# Running a php based facebook app in Heroku Scheduler

Tags: php, heroku, scheduled-tasks

I have a facebook app written in php hosted in Heroku server. I want to schedule this app to run everyday automatically. I have added an add on called Heroku Scheduler to this app. I tried setting up a task in Heroku Scheduler but I couldn't locate the facebook app in the directory. When I used http://apps.facebook.com/namespace/ in the shell prompt, it is saying unknown path. I have spent a lot of time trying to figure this out but in vain.I googled but cudn't find any documentation.
All I want to do is to schedule a task to run my php based FB app automatically. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks
Ganesh

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but you should read the facebook docs first. Facebook apps are just casual sites that are shown in a html frame (or div). you have to create a fb acc, a fb app acount and then simply link it. done.